# How can i Insert Data in Salesforce using WSDL file of Salesforce using Query?

Tags: soql, wsdl2apex

Query :

```
INSERT INTO Customers (CustomerName, ContactName, Address, City, PostalCode, Country)
VALUES ('Cardinal', 'Tom B. Erichsen', 'Skagen 21', 'Stavanger', '4006', 'Norway');
```

I can get data using "**Select Query** " in Salesforce WSDL file. 
At same way can i use query based CRUD Operations in Salesforce.

```
QueryResult queryResult = null;
String SOQL = "";
string productid = "";   
SOQL = "select Id from Product2 where ProductCode = 'Test'";
queryResult = sfdcBinding.query(SOQL);
```

Comment: I don't think you can use WSDL in Jquery. You can try sForce library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOQL is query only. It won't perform inserts, updates, or deletes. Those are referred to as Data Manipulation Language (DML) operations instead and are handled by separate API methods.

Instead you should use [create()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_create.htm) or [upsert()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_upsert.htm) to create new records via the APIs.