# How to Create Table in Salesforce using Partner WSDL file in C#?

Tags: soql

I am using Salesforce Partner WSDL file 40.0.

I want to create new table in Salesforce. How can i do it in c#.

My Query :

```
CREATE TABLE mathantable 
(
Id System.String, 
Mark System.String, 
Name System.String
)
```

I tried this query but I got *Create Not Support Malformed query* Error.

Comment: Tables cannot be created this way in Salesforce. They are called Objects in Salesforce and you have to use another approach to create a table(Object) in Salesforce. Have a look at this: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_createMetadata.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Partner API isn't intended for creating new sObjects (what you might think of as tables) or fields. Instead you should be using either the Metadata API to create a new sObject. The Tooling API can also be used to create new fields on the sObject.

As with your prior question [SOQL is query *only*](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/201841/102). It's important to remember that SOQL is not SQL. There are similarities in how you query records, but that doesn't extend to any other database operations like creating tables or updating records.

From [Which API Do I Use?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=integrate_what_is_api.htm&type=0)

> **When to Use SOAP API**
> SOAP API provides a powerful, convenient, and simple SOAP-based web services interface for interacting with Salesforce. You can use SOAP API to create, retrieve, update, or delete records. You can also use SOAP API to perform searches and much more.
>
> **When to Use Metadata API**
> Use Metadata API to retrieve, deploy, create, update, or delete customizations for your org. The most common use is to migrate changes from a sandbox or testing org to your production environment. Metadata API is intended for managing customizations and for building tools that can manage the metadata model, not the data itself.
>
> **When to Use Tooling API**
> Use Tooling API to integrate Salesforce metadata with other systems.

There is some general code in [Creating a custom object using REST API](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/20767/102) that demonstrates how to create a new sObject/CustomObject via the Metadata API.